# Crash caused by [NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:]

Tags: ios, crash

my app got a critical crash since apple releases 10.3.0 version. Here the crash log. Does anyone have any idea about this? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Could you please  show your log

Comment: Sorry, I only have the log from Crashlytics.

Comment: I'd suggest to try to make it more clear, what's actual file that caused the crash? do you have any idea of what's the scenario to causes this?

Comment: If log exist, it would be clear but based on your Crashlytics...
Maybe Key value changing occurred simultaneously in different thread? In this case we should use **@synchronized {}**